# pandas matplotlib resizing and removing labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

I am using pandas matplotlib to plot data from dataFrame.
I'm doing it like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': dataFrame['Country'], labelName: 'Infant mort. rate'})
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',x= dataFrame['Country'])
ax.set_ylabel('Infant mort. rate')
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am trying to get rid of the label on the top right corner ('color blue' infant mort. rate)
and I want to resize the entire window so I can see the xlabel (right now it's hidden under the white line at the bottom)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating your figure and axes object explicitly, pass some additional options to `df.plot(...)` and call `fig.tight_layout()` before showing the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': dataFrame['Country'], labelName: 'Infant mort. rate'})
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x=dataFrame['Country'], legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Infant mort. rate')
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```